# How to package and execute binary asset using pkg?

Tags: node.js, vercel

Trying to package app using [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg).

When packaged app runs and binary [asset](https://github.com/vercel/pkg#assets) is executed using `child_process`, following error is thrown.

```
Error: spawn /snapshot/test-cli/deps/darwin/arm64/argon2 ENOENT
```

I confirmed `argon2` binary was packaged using `DEBUG_PKG=1` (see [debug mode](https://github.com/vercel/pkg#exploring-virtual-file-system-embedded-in-debug-mode)).

According to [comment](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/342#issuecomment-1317771944) on [issue](https://github.com/vercel/pkg/issues/342), it appears OS cannot run binaries located in virtual file system.

Is there a way around this without copying binaries to OS file system?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue while extracting the zip file using [7zip npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/7zip-min) so instead of using the npm package I added the `7za` command in my PATH and used that using [`exec` function in node.](https://stackabuse.com/executing-shell-commands-with-node-js/)